# Can't create new EJB project in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ejb, java-ee-6

I have installed eclipse and added jboss and wildfly. In the tutorial that i was following the guy created a new ejb project in eclipse from file->new->EJB Project.
[this is the tutorial screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kV1pH.png)
But when i tried to create it in my eclipse IDE, i didn't find the option of creating new ejb project.
[this is a screenshot from my eclipse IDE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ckp73.png)

Even when i searched in others i didn't find it.
[others screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SADG4.png)

can any one help please :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is probably you are using Eclipse for Java Developer.
Possible option you could try:

- Try using "Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers". You can find it here https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/
- Go to Eclipse -> Help -> Install new software and choose the Web, XML, Java EE plugin and install it.
  [Install new sofware](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MqSLL.png)

Please mention the Eclipse you are using in your post.

Comment: yeah it's eclipse ide for java devolepers

Comment: i have installed java EE plugin like you said and the problem fixed, thank you very much <3